WalletConnect not updating user balance after payment transaction in React app
I am working on a React application where I use WalletConnect for handling crypto payments. The payment flow involves connecting a wallet, initiating a transaction, and then updating the user balance(in the wallet-connect modal). However, after a successful transaction, the user balance is not updating as expected. Here are the relevant parts of my code:
import { createWeb3Modal, useWeb3ModalTheme } from "@web3modal/wagmi/react";
import { defaultWagmiConfig } from "@web3modal/wagmi/react/config";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { WagmiProvider } from "wagmi";
import { arbitrum, bsc, mainnet, polygon } from "wagmi/chains";

interface Web3ModalProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const projectId = "72c5504d7004e0e5f13e324ed2096ce2";

const metadata = {
    name: "Web3Modal",
    description: "Web3Modal Example",
    url: "http://localhost:5173/",
    icons: ["https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/37784886"],
};

const chains = [mainnet, polygon, bsc] as const;
const config = defaultWagmiConfig({
    chains,
    projectId,
    metadata,
});

createWeb3Modal({
    wagmiConfig: config,
    projectId,
    enableAnalytics: true,
    enableOnramp: true,
    themeMode: "dark",
    themeVariables: {
        "--w3m-accent": "#c0983b",
        "--w3m-font-size-master": "8",
    },
});

export function Web3ModalProvider({ children }: Web3ModalProviderProps) {
    return <WagmiProvider config={config}>{children}</WagmiProvider>;
}


import { CopyAllOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Backdrop, Box, Button, CircularProgress, Container, IconButton, Paper, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, useMatch, useNavigate } from "react-location";
import { useNotifications } from "~/context/Providers/notificationContext";
import DefaultLayout from "~/layouts/DefaultLayout";
import { formatPrice } from "~/utils/helpers";
import { parseEther } from "viem";
import { generateCoinpayment } from "~/utils/hooks/apis/payment-api";
import { LoaderData } from "../CoinPayment/CoinPayment.loader";
import "../CoinPayment/CoinPayment.scss";
import { useAccount, useSendTransaction, useBalance } from "wagmi";
import { useWeb3ModalState } from "@web3modal/wagmi/react";
import SuccessModal from "~/components/Modals/SuccessModal";
import ErrorModal from "~/components/Modals/ErrorModal";
import { COINPAYMENTS_FEE } from "~/utils/constants";
import { getBalance } from "viem/actions";

function CoinPayment() {
    let { order } = useMatch().data as Partial<LoaderData>;
    let { orderId } = useMatch().params as { orderId: string };
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    let { addToast } = useNotifications();
    const account = useAccount();
    const { address, chainId } = account;
    const { data: balanceData, refetch: refetchBalance } = useBalance({ address });
    const [selectedCurrency, setSelectedCurrency] = useState<"ETH" | "MATIC.POLY" | "BNB.BSC">(account.chainId === 1 ? "ETH" : account.chainId === 137 ? "MATIC.POLY" : "BNB.BSC");
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [openError, setOpenError] = useState(false);
    const [openSuccess, setOpenSuccess] = useState(false);

    const [coinpaymentDetails, setCoinpaymentDetails] = useState<{
        amount: string;
        txn_id: string;
        address: string;
        confirms_needed: string;
        timeout: number;
        checkout_url: string;
        status_url: string;
        qrcode_url: string;
    }>();

    const { data: transactionData, status, sendTransaction } = useSendTransaction();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (account.chainId) {
            setSelectedCurrency(() => {
                const newCurrency = account.chainId === 1 ? "ETH" : account.chainId === 137 ? "MATIC.POLY" : "BNB.BSC";
                handleCoinpaymentGeneration(newCurrency);
                return newCurrency;
            });
        }
    }, [account.chainId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === "success") {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setOpenSuccess(true);
            addToast({ id: "payment-success", message: "Payment successful", severity: "success" });
            refetchBalance(); // Refresh the balance after a successful transaction
        } else if (status === "error") {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setOpenError(true);
            addToast({ id: "payment-error", message: "Payment failed", severity: "error" });
        }
    }, [status]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (address) {
            refetchBalance()
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log("Initial balance refetch successful:", result);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Initial refetch failed:", error);
                });
        }
    }, [chainId, refetchBalance]);

    if (!order) {
        addToast({ id: `Payment`, message: "Something went wrong", severity: "warning" });
        return <Navigate to={"/store"} />;
    }

    const handleCoinpaymentGeneration = async (currency: "ETH" | "MATIC.POLY" | "BNB.BSC") => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const coinResp = await generateCoinpayment(orderId, currency);
            setIsLoading(false);
            if (coinResp.paymentIntent) {
                setCoinpaymentDetails(coinResp.paymentIntent);
            } else {
                addToast({ id: `Payment`, message: coinResp?.message || "Something went wrong", severity: "error" });
                navigate({ to: "/dashboard" });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Payment generation error:", error);
            setIsLoading(false);
            addToast({ id: `Payment`, message: "Something went wrong", severity: "error" });
            navigate({ to: "/dashboard" });
        }
    };

    const handlePayment = async () => {
        if (!coinpaymentDetails) return;
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            await sendTransaction({
                to: coinpaymentDetails.address as `0x${string}`,
                value: parseEther(coinpaymentDetails.amount),
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Transaction error:", error);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setOpenError(true);
            addToast({ id: "payment-error", message: "Payment failed", severity: "error" });
        }
    };

    const copyLink = async (url: string, title: string) => {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
        addToast({ id: "address-copy-success", message: `${title} copied!`, severity: "success" });
    };

    const handleCloseErrorModal = () => {
        setOpenError(false);
    };

    const handleCloseSuccessModal = () => {
        setOpenSuccess(false);
        navigate({ to: "/dashboard" });
    };

    return (
        <DefaultLayout variant="secondary" title="Payment" toolbar="none" pageID="payment-page" backLocation={`/order/${orderId}`}>
            <Container maxWidth="sm" disableGutters>
                <Box>
                    <Box sx={{ mb: 1.5, display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                        <Typography variant="h5">Wallet Payment</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
                            {formatPrice(parseInt(order.total.toString().split(".")[0]) * (1 + COINPAYMENTS_FEE), 2)}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>
                    <>
                        <Paper sx={{ p: { xs: 2, sm: 3 }, mb: { xs: 2, sm: 3 }, textAlign: "center" }}>
                            <Typography variant="body1" color="text.secondary" sx={{ mb: 0.5, letterSpacing: "0.01rem" }}>
                                SEND:
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
                                {Number(coinpaymentDetails?.amount).toFixed(3)} {selectedCurrency}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body1" color="text.secondary" sx={{ mb: 1.2, letterSpacing: "0.01rem" }}>
                                TO WALLET ADDRESS:
                            </Typography>

                            <Box sx={{ pl: 2, py: 0.75, display: "flex", alignItems: "center", m: 0, mb: 3, borderRadius: 1, border: "1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" }}>
                                <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ flex: 1, wordBreak: "break-word", lineHeight: 1, pr: 1 }}>
                                    {coinpaymentDetails?.address}
                                </Typography>
                                <IconButton title="Copy Address" onClick={() => copyLink(coinpaymentDetails?.address || "", "address")}>
                                    <CopyAllOutlined sx={{ color: "text.secondary" }} />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Box>
                            <Button variant="contained" fullWidth sx={{ mx: "auto" }} onClick={handlePayment} disabled={!coinpaymentDetails}>
                                Pay directly with your wallet
                            </Button>
                        </Paper>
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            sx={{ mb: 1 }}
                            onClick={() => {
                                navigate({ to: "/" });
                            }}
                        >
                            Go to Dashboard
                        </Button>
                    </>
                </Box>
            </Container>
            <Backdrop sx={{ color: "#fff", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }} open={isLoading}>
                <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
            </Backdrop>
            <SuccessModal openSuccess={openSuccess} handleCloseSuccess={handleCloseSuccessModal} message="Payment successful" />
            <ErrorModal openError={openError} handleCloseErrorModal={handleCloseErrorModal} errorHeading="Wallet Confirmation Error" errorMessage={"Payment failed. Please try again"} />
        </DefaultLayout>
    );
}


I have tried using the refetchBalance after the payment transaction, it gets the correct balance but I am unsure of how to update the wallet-connect modal's balance as it doesn't take in any parameters.
<Box>
   <w3m-button />
</Box>

